# Model turns into tuple in django's view. Whata hell?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to save a string (session hash) into django's model, but something is going wrong..
When I try to update the string, the model turns into a tuple causing AttributeError.

At the beginning everything was in a one 'post' function in view and yet not working. I tried to devide that stuff into functions, but it still does not help. Before the assignment type(session) says that 'session' is a model, not tuple.

View function code:

```py
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    form = self.form_class(data)
    if form.is_valid():
        phone = form.cleaned_data.get('phone')
        code = form.cleaned_data.get('code')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')

        session = Session.objects.get_or_create(phone=phone, user=request.user.telegramuser)

        if code and password:
            return utils.sign_in(session, phone, code, password)
        elif code:
            return utils.sign_in(session, phone, code)
        elif phone:
            return utils.send_code_request(session, phone)


    return JsonResponse({'state': 'none'})
```

utils.send_code_request and sign_in have the same structure

```py
def send_code_request(session, phone):
    result = asyncio.run(_send_code_request(phone))
    # result - {
    #     'state': 'ok',
    #     'session': 'Hfkdi...AaF24s'
    # }

    if result['state'] == 'ok':
        session.update_session(result.pop('session'))
    return JsonResponse(result)
```

Manager

```py
class DefaultManager(models.Manager):
    def get_or_create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return self.create(*args, **kwargs)
```

Error:

```
Internal Server Error: /sessions/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ipyth\Documents\projects\telegram-sendall\.env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\ipyth\Documents\projects\telegram-sendall\.env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\ipyth\Documents\projects\telegram-sendall\.env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ipyth\Documents\projects\telegram-sendall\.env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ipyth\Documents\projects\telegram-sendall\.env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 52, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ipyth\Documents\projects\telegram-sendall\.env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ipyth\Documents\projects\telegram-sendall\sendall\views.py", line 78, in post
    return utils.send_code_request(session, phone)
  File "C:\Users\ipyth\Documents\projects\telegram-sendall\sendall\utils.py", line 46, in send_code_request
    session.update_session(result.pop('session'))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'update_session'
[23/Jul/2019 23:51:35] "POST /sessions/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 86600
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_or_create` does indeed return a tuple, of the object and a created flag. Either capture both:

```
session, created = Session.objects.get_or_create(phone=phone...)
```

Or, use `create` instead.

Or even better, use the form save method:

```
session = form.save()
```